# Override for global authorisation policy in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, model-view-controller, authorization

I have a problem with overriding global authorisation filter / policy in my app (back-end api accessible from front-end / swagger / postman).

First - what I want to achieve:

- By default, all controllers should require authentication and should use a `Default` configured policy (will paste code bellow in example).
  That goes for all controllers / actions either not marked by `[Authorise]` attribute or marked by one without specifying concrete policy
- This `Default` policy should not be evaluated when either controller or action is decorated with `[Authorise]` attribute that does specify particular policy - in my case: `[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policies.NotBoundUser))]`
- Policies should not block access to things like swagger etc.
- Behaviour of this mechanism should respect optional controller / action that is decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`

Now, as for my code:
I defined 2 policies mentioned before:

```cs
public static AuthorizationPolicy Default
    => new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim(Claims.UserId)
        .Build();

public static AuthorizationPolicy NotBoundUser
    => new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireAssertion(ctx => !ctx.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == Claims.UserId))
        .Build();
```

Difference between them is that `Default` requires user to have certain claim (Claims.UserId) that is added by custom `IClaimsTransformation` implementation and the other one requires **lack** of said claim

In my `Startup.cs` I have added following:

```cs
services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        options.Filters.Add(new OverridableAuthorizeFilter(Policies.Default));
        options.UseMaybeModelBinding();
        options.UseRouteAndBodyModelBinder();
    })
```

which points us to custom implementation of `OverridableAuthorizeFilter`, which is:

```cs
public class OverridableAuthorizeFilter : AuthorizeFilter, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public OverridableAuthorizeFilter(AuthorizationPolicy policy) : base(policy)
    {
    }
    
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var action = context.ActionDescriptor;

        if (action.EndpointMetadata.Any(em => em.GetType() == typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)))
        {
            return;
        }

        var controller = action.FilterDescriptors.FirstOrDefault()?.Filter?.GetType();
        if (controller != null && controller.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true))
        {
            return;
        }

        await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
    }
}
```

Now, next thing added was Authorisation:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.DefaultPolicy = Policies.Default;
    o.AddPolicy(nameof(Policies.NotBoundUser), Policies.NotBoundUser);
});
```

And, lastly - I added required middleware to `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

After all of this I started to test this solution with example controller what should return user data from claims, which are decoded from JWT token sent on each call to api

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer();
// Options are configured using options pattern
```

Now, as for test controller - there are 3 methods for testing purposes:

- `GetUserData` decorated with `[Authorize]`
- `GetUserData2` decorated with `[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policies.NotBoundUser))]`
- `GetUserData3` which is not decorated by any form of `[Authorise]` attribute
  Controller as a whole is also not decorated with it.

**Now current effect is like this:**

If user **does not have** required claim (mentioned in Policies) and is authenticated:

- `GetUserData` returns `403` - Correct
- `GetUserData2` returns `403` - Incorrect - should return user data
- `GetUserData3` returns `403` - Correct

If user **have** required claim (mentioned in Policies) and is authenticated:

- `GetUserData` returns valid data - Correct
- `GetUserData2` returns `403` - Correct
- `GetUserData3` returns valid data - Correct

It feels like maybe both policies are being evaluated? Its just a hunch...

I am really out of ideas as of right now - I tried (at least I think so) most of the solutions for similar issues from SO - but with no success.

I also experimented with using `AddAuthorization` and specifying `FallbackPolicy` attitudinally, without `options.Filters.Add(new OverridableAuthorizeFilter(Policies.Default));` in `AddMvc`, but this unfortunately locked down everything including swagger...

Please let me know if I can give you some additional information about my code, will gladly do it.

Answer (score 0):

`FallbackPolicy` determins actions with no `[Authorize]`, `Defaultpolicy` determins actions with simple `[Authorize]` without specifying concrete policy.
In my test, combine the policies will work as you envision.

**Program.cs**

```
...

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    //add the policy service of both
    options.DefaultPolicy = Policies.Default();
    options.FallbackPolicy = Policies.Default();
    options.AddPolicy(nameof(Policies.NotBoundUser), Policies.NotBoundUser());
});

...
```

Then the `Services.AddMvc` is unnecessary.

You can see in my controller, no extra attribute needed, and `[AllowAnonymous]` is respected.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthenticateController(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        //Your own logic of user claim control
        //for testing I simply coded
        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("UserID", user.Id.ToString())
            };

            var token = GetToken(authClaims);

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
    {
        var userExists = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (userExists != null)
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });

        IdentityUser user = new()
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            UserName = model.Username
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });

        return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    private JwtSecurityToken GetToken(List<Claim> authClaims)
    {
        var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
            claims: authClaims,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

        return token;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetData1")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData1()
    {
        return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "GetData1!" });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policies.NotBoundUser))]
    [Route("GetData2")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData2()
    {
        return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "GetData2!" });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetData3")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData3()
    {
        return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "GetData3!" });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetData4")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData4()
    {
        return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "GetData4!" });
    }
}
```

No Swagger blocked

[image]

When no-claim user authenticated

[image: 403]
[image: valid]
[image: 403]
[image: valid]

When claim user authenticated

[image: valid]
[image: 403]
[image: valid]
[image: valid]

Comment: Hey, thanks for such a detailed answer, unfortunately there are still some problems - given that i removed adding global filter and set Fallback policy:
- I moved UseAuthorisation and UseAuthentication to after UseOpenApi - that unlocked swagger.
As for endpoints - now all of the enpoints are returning `403` code - it looks like all of the policies are being applied even though one of endpoints policies were set to authorise only (no additional checks).

Comment: Basically it looks like when Fallback Policy is set, it is always applied in addition to policy set on controller action

Answer (score 0):

Alright - it seems that not using `UseRouting()` and `UseEndpoints()` in `Configure` method was causing issues.

After adding and configuring those two - I've got everything working, including Default and Fallback policies.